# Fatal error: pdo_sqlsrv_db_handle_factory using pdo_sqlsrv for PHP in Mac. What to do?

Tags: php, pdo

Installing PDO_sqlsrv in my macs have really been an hassle.

I always follow the instructions stated in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-2017#installing-the-drivers-on-macos-el-capitan-sierra-and-high-sierra

yet while sometimes everything works well others it's an hassle.

This one I never found before and would like to check if someone came up with it too and if they found any solution?

I'm using PHP@7.1 for HomeBrew and High Sierra

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue in the strangest way.

Based on what was proposed here for Ubuntu:
https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/issues/161#issuecomment-254046975

I set the locale in the PHP as:

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');

And it magically worked. I'll probably just go and set the default in PHP.ini to this locale and everything should be ok.